# Visual Studio Add-In for QT5 still gives errors

Tags: visual-studio, qt5

I have installed the new Add-In for Visual Studio 2008 in order to debug QT5 classes.

Most of the instances are correctly visualized during debugging thanks to the new definitions. I still have errors in visualizing QVectors (and probably other structures).

In particular the definition of QVector introduced in Common7\Packages\Debugger\autoexp.dat seems not valid:

```
 $c.p->array[$i]
```

p (and thus array) is no more present in QVector.

This should be replaced by something like:

```
(float*)($c.d + $c.d->offset)[$i]
```

in case of a `QVector<float>`. 
I am not an expert in the visual studio sintax used in autoexp.dat. How can this be fixed for the general case? The cast should be generalized to the template.

Or there is a much simpler solution that avoids dealing with autoexp?

Answer (score 4):

After some fiddling, I've found the following worked with Qt 5.1.0 and Visual Studio 2010:

```
;  expr: $c.p->array[$i], 
   expr: (($T1*)((char*)(&$c.d->ref)+(int)$c.d->offset))[$i],
```

replaced 3 times in the QVector<*> block. $Tn refers to the n-th type argument given as * in the 1st line of the AutoExpand rule.

Hope this helps,

Reinhard

Comment: It's so awesome, now i can see data in QVector, thanks so much!